# Chamar método dentro de URL no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tenho uma página com um link "voltar". Existe alguma forma de chamar o método `back()` do Laravel dentro do `href` do link? 
Esse código não funciona, mas quero alguma coisa do tipo

`href="{{URL::to(back())}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente o seguinte:

```
href="{{URL::previous()}}"
```

Pode também fazer com javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">...</a>
```

Comment: Não deu certo. Voltou para a página anterior à que eu queria, ou seja, voltou duas páginas.

Comment: Estranho, acabei de testar e resultou aqui. E porque não usa javascript @AmandaLima? `<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1);return false;">...</a>`

Comment: Talvez não tenha funcionado porque a página que quero voltar é vinda de um formulário. Quando usei `{{URL::previous()}}` voltou para a página do formulário.

Comment: Com javascript funcionou, obrigada!

Comment: De nada @AmandaLima. Vou editar a resposta para incluir essa alternativa também